# Access Location when an app is killed/terminated on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, location

I'm trying to build an app based on notifications according to the location of the user.

I've searched for while a solution for the situation where the user kills the app (meaning not anymore in the background).

According to Ricky (http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended) we can do this thanks to the LaunchOptions key "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey".

Does anybody knows if it works well with iOS9 or have any other solution ?(Doesn't work when I try)

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Nothing... I think it's not possible, 10 minutes is max to run app in background